# php pdo Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having issues which a php file when trying to update table values in a MySql database. I have tried different ways to overcome this issue but have not been successful even after looking through stack overflow and google!

I have a modal which gets the info from a table populated by php which i then am attempting to update the value for course_title using php PDO however i keep getting this error:

'Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE course_code = NULL' at line 2'

if anyone could shine some light as to what i am doing wrong i would be much appreciative!

the php file:

```
<?php

    if(!isset( $_POST['course_title'], $_POST['course_code']))
    {
$message = $_POST['course_title'] ." ". $_POST['course_code'];
    }

include "db_conx.php";

try
{
$db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

$db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = $db_conx->prepare("UPDATE course_details SET course_title = :course_title,  
    WHERE course_code = :course_code");

$course_title = $_POST['course_title'];
$course_code = $_POST['course_code'];

$sql->bindParam(':course_title', $course_title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(':course_code', $course_code, PDO::PARAM_STR);


/*** execute the prepared statement ***/
$sql->execute();

/*** success message ***/
 $message ='record updated';
 } 
 catch(Exception $e)
 {
$message = 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}

 ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Update Course</title>
</head>
 <body>
<p><?php echo $message; ?>
</body>
    </html>
```

the modal:

```
    <div id="editModel" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Update Record: </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="text-primary">Please make any changes and click 'update' to save or 'cancel' to return</p>
        <form id="updateForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="course_code" class="control-label">Course Code:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="course_code" readonly="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="course_title" class="control-label">Course Title:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="course_title">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button name="cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button name= "update" value="update" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myCall();">Update</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks :)

**UPDATE - the initial syntax issue has been resolved thanks to @Rizier123 however i am now encountering an issue which is 'Undefined index: course_title' 'Undefined index: course_code' error for this code:

```
    $course_title = $_POST['course_title'];
    $course_code = $_POST['course_code'];
```

any ideas why that could be? i have matched the input values to the PDO prepared statements

Comment: `:course_title, ` <- Remove the comma

Comment: @Rizier123 thank you! that did solve the main error message but now i have an 'Undefined index: course_title' 'Undefined index: course_code' error for this code:  $course_title = $_POST['course_title'];
 $course_code = $_POST['course_code']; any ideas why that could be?

Comment: You're checking that the POST values aren't set then trying to access them.  `if(!isset( $_POST['course_title'], $_POST['course_code']))
    {
$message = $_POST['course_title'] ." ". $_POST['course_code'];` If they aren't set they are undefined.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did set them later on in the try catch code by using $ course_title = $_POST ['course_title']; and edited the message to 'try again' for the if (!isset. ..) however I am still getting the undefined errors :/

Comment: Yes but what you're saying in your first line of code is "if $_POST['course_title'] isn't set and $_POST['course_code'] isn't set execute this block of code". Then in that block of code the PHP is trying to find those unset values which is why you have the notice...maybe you don't want the `!` there?

Answer (score 0):

Try using name attribute instead of id:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="course_code_id" name="course_code" readonly="">
```

id attribute should be used for styling in css, and the name attribute should be used in order to get the value with PHP when posting your form.

Also in your php script you should check if those values are set, like @chris85 pointed.

Comment: When I use the name attribute the modal is unable to locate the value stored in course_title for some reason. I have a check at the top of the php page which checks if the values are set before continuing but the error message isn't returned which leads me to believe it is grabbing something

Comment: You can use same values for both attributes without worries about these two will interfere with each other.. Try using course_title and course_code for both id and name.

Comment: Brilliant will give that a go and see how it works (y) many thanks

Comment: Also use var_dump($_POST); to see which values are actually sent.